# how to write query with "with" using laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel

How to make with laravel a query with with like the example below
Thank you

```
with s as (select s.id from s)
select a.*
from a
left join s on s.id = a.s_id
...
```

Comment: You should give us an ectual example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WITH clauses are not supported by Eloquent. You can either pass in a raw query

```
$sql = <<<SQL
with s as (select s.id from s)
select a.*
from a
left join s on s.id = a.s_id
...
SQL;

$results = DB::select($sql);
```

Or use a package that adds this functionality like [`staudenmeir/laravel-cte`](https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-cte)

```php
DB::query()
    ->withExpression('s', fn ($query) => $query->select('s.id')->from('s'))
    ->select('a.*')
    ->from('a')
    ->leftJoin('s', 's.id', 'a.s_id')
    ...
```